# retaining input value after refresh in php

Tags: php

I am trying to retain the value of the input if the form refresh with the earlier input the user filled in. But every time i make error and the page refresh still comes back empty.

```
    if ( isset($_POST['make']) && isset($_POST['model']) && isset($_POST['year']) && isset($_POST['mileage'])){
            if(strlen($_POST['make']) < 1 || strlen($_POST['model']) < 1 || strlen($_POST['year']) < 1 || strlen($_POST['mileage']) < 1){
                $_SESSION["error"] = "All values are required";
                header('Location: add.php');
                return; 
            }
```

from here i tried to pass the post make value to the session as a parameter but, it didn't work either!

```
            elseif (strlen($_POST['make']) < 1 ){
                $_SESSION["error"] = "Make is required.";
                $_SESSION['make'] = $_POST['make'];
                header("Location: add.php?make=".$_POST['make']); 
                return;
            }
```

Then i pass it as part of the url on refresh as and used a global get value still didn't work either!

```
            else if (strlen($_POST['model']) < 1 ){
                $_SESSION["error"] = "Model is required.";
                header("Location: add.php?model=".$_POST['model']);   
                return;
            }
            else if(strlen($_POST['year']) < 1 ){
                $_SESSION["error"] = "Year is required.";
                header("Location: add.php?year=".$_POST['year']);        
                return;
            }
            else if( strlen($_POST['mileage']) < 1){
                $_SESSION["error"] = "Mileage is required.";
                header("Location: add.php?mileage=".$_POST['mileage']);
                return;
            }
            else if (!is_numeric($_POST['year']) || !is_numeric($_POST['mileage'])){
                $_SESSION["error"] = "Mileage and year must be numeric";
                header('Location: add.php');
                return;
            }else {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO autos (make, model, year, mileage) 
                    VALUES (:make, :model, :year, :mileage)";
            // // echo("<pre>\n".$sql."\n</pre>\n");
            // $opt = "Record Inserted";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':make' => $_POST['make'],
                ':model' => $_POST['model'],
                ':year' => $_POST['year'],
                ':mileage' => $_POST['mileage']));
            }
            $_SESSION["success"] =  "added";
            header('Location: view.php');
            return;
        }
```

Then i changed it here to listen for the submit and when the submit is set  all value of post should be passed as session value but, still come empty.

```
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $_SESSION['make'] = $_POST['make'];
            $_SESSION['model'] = $_POST['model'];
            $_SESSION['year'] = $_POST['year'];
            $_SESSION['mileage'] = $_POST['mileage'];
        }
    ?>



     <?php
        if ( isset($_SESSION["error"]) ) {
            echo('<p style="color:red">'.$_SESSION["error"]."</p>\n");
            unset($_SESSION["error"]);
        }
    ?>
    <br>
    <p>Adding  A New Auto</p>
    <form id="autoAdd" method="post">
    <p>Make:
```

I then check if the get is set and try to pass it to the value and if not it should output the input without value.

```
        <?php
            if(isset($_GET['make'])) {
                // $make = $_GET['make'];
                $make = htmlentities($_SESSION['make']);
                echo '<input type="text" name="make" size="40" value="'.$make.'">';
            }
            else{  
                echo '<input type="text" name="make" size="40">';
            }
        ?>
    </p>
    <p>Model:
```

I then check if the get is set and try to pass it to the value and if not it should output the input without value.

```
        <?php
            if(isset($_GET['model'])) {
                $model = $_GET['model'];
                echo '<input type="text" name="model" size="40" value="'.$model.'">'; 
            }
            else{ 
                echo '<input type="text" name="model" size="40">'; 
            }
        ?>
    </p>
    <p>Year:
```

I then check if the get is set and try to pass it to the value and if not it should output the input without value.

```
        <?php
            if(isset($_GET['year'])) {
                $year = $_GET['year'];
                echo '<input type="text" name="year" size="40" value="'.$year.'">';
            }
            else{
                echo '<input type="text" name="year" size="40">';
            }
        ?>
    </p>
    <p>Mileage:
```

I then check if the get is set and try to pass it to the value and if not it should output the input without value.

```
        <?php
            if(isset($_GET['mileage'])) {
                $mileage = $_GET['mileage'];
                echo '<input type="text" name="mileage" size="40" value="'.$mileage.'">';
            }
            else{
                echo '<input type="text" name="mileage" size="40">';
            }
        ?>
    </p>
    <button type="submit" value="Add">Add</button>
```

Comment: research `$_SESSION`

Comment: that guy has no subject related to what i am looking for! ??

Comment: `retaining input value after refresh in php` -> page title, did you read what a `$_SESSION` does?

Comment: haven't you seen how i pass the error back tot the same page after refresh? i tried that it didn't work

Comment: but if you change from `$_GET` to `$_SESSION` you no longer need `$_GET`. You just use `$_POST` (as is standard nowadays) and then set the data with `$_SESSION` and if `isset $_SESSION['error']`, `echo`?

Comment: <?php
            if(isset($_GET['make'])) {
                // $make = $_GET['make'];
                $make = htmlentities($_SESSION['make']);
                echo '<input type="text" name="make" size="40" value="'.$make.'">';
            }
            else{  
                echo '<input type="text" name="make" size="40">';
            }
        ?>
    </p>

Comment: see the GET is commented out

Comment: did you put `session_start()` before using `$_SESSION` ?

Comment: yes and i already used session in this very same file handling error

Answer (score 0):

I got it!!
I created variables and pass the Global POST as their values like this:

```
$make = $_POST['make'];
```

And then changed the header and the condition test cases as follows:

```
 if(strlen($make) < 1 ){
     $_SESSION["error"] = "Make is required.";
     header("Location: add.php?autosInput=mileage&make=$make&model=$model&year=$year&mileage=$mileage");

     return;
}
```

And left the input side with the `$GET` as usual that does the magic